# How to edit html file from an another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I want to select element with `sidebar` id in `downloader.html` from an another html document (`settings.html`).

downloader.html

```
    <body>
<div class="ui visible left vertical thin sidebar menu" id='sidebar'>
    <div class='item'>
        <img class='ui medium image' src='./../../resources/images/logo_256x256.png'>
    </div>
    <a class="item" id='dashboard_btn'>
        <i class="desktop icon"></i>
        Dashboard
      </a>
    <a class="item" id='statistics_btn'>
        <i class="area chart icon"></i>
        Statistics
      </a>
    <a class="item" id='settings_btn'>
        <i class="settings icon"></i>
        Settings
      </a>
</div>
<div class='dimmed pusher'>
    <button class="ui icon button" id='sidebar_btn'>
        <i class="angle double left icon" id='sidebar_btn_icon'></i>
    </button>
    <div id='content'>
        <!-- All content goes here. -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebar_btn').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').sidebar('toggle');

            $('#sidebar_btn_icon').toggleClass('right');
        });

        $("#dashboard_btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#content").load("./items/dashboard/dashboard.html");
        });
        $("#statistics_btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#content").load("./items/statistics/statistics.html");
        });
        $("#settings_btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#content").load("./items/settings/settings.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

settings.html

```
<body>
<div class='center'>
    <h2 class="ui icon header">
        <i class="settings icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            Settings
            <div class="sub header">Sample text.</div>
        </div>
    </h2>
    <div class='center child'>
        <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
            <input name="public" type="checkbox">
            <label>Dark theme.</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    //Select 'sidebar' element from downloader.html using jquery
</script>
```

Please, do not pay attention to mixed `'` with `"` in html code. It is my fault and it will be fixed before app release.

Comment: What should occur once the element is selected?

Comment: From which user action do you want to "select" the `#sidebar` and what to you want to do with it? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.load()` with hash set within "settings.html"

```
$("#element").load("downloader.html #sidebar")
```

Comment: `settings.html` is loaded into element `#content` of `downloader.html`...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Then the Question may truly be absolutely unclear. Perhaps OP will chime in